# vi copy and yank mixing up

Tags: vim, vi

In the past, copying the contents of files by highlighting the contents are not mixing up with yank/delete lines in VI. In other words, after copying, I still can yank/delete those unwanted lines before I paste my content.
But now after delete/yank lines, the copied contents now become those deleted/yank lines. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you've aliased the system clipboard with the unnamed register.  You do this by setting the option `:se clipboard=unnamed`  Set it to something else (or unset it) to undo that.

Comment: Well, "vi" or "vim"? If "vim", do you have a personal config (`vimrc`)? If "vim", what is the output of `:set mouse?`?

Comment: :set mouse
mouse=